# Google Line Chart - Unknown lines Issue

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, linechart

I am trying to generate a multicolor line chart refer [jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/c8ngyz0b/)
The chart that's being generated by Google chart shows three straight lines (red, green and blue) which should not be part of the chart at all.
See attached image [image]

When I am rendering the chart of individual colors, in that case, the chart is coming up fine but when I am combining them together, in that case, one can see these straight lines appearing out of nowhere.

Here's the code snippet, refer jsfiddle for the actual code

```
    google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawAxisTickColors);

    function drawAxisTickColors() {
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn('number', 'Bets');
                data.addColumn('number', 'Values');
    data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'style'});
          data.addRows([[5,100,"color:#D3D3D3"],[10,200,"color:#D3D3D3"],[15,300,"color:#D3D3D3"]]);

          var options = {
                    height: 450,
                    title: 'Monte Carlo',
                    curveType: 'function',
                    legend: 'none',
                    backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent' },
                    intervals: { 'style': 'line' },
                    hAxis: {
                        title: 'Bets',
                        textStyle: {
                            color: '#33465C'
                        },
                        titleTextStyle: {
                            color: '#33465C'
                        }
                    },
                    vAxis: {
                        title: 'Results',
                        textStyle: {
                            color: '#33465C'
                        },
                        titleTextStyle: {
                            color: '#33465C'
                        }
                    },
                    titleTextStyle: {
                        color: '#33465C'
                    },

                };
          var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }
```

Any guidance to resolve this will be much appreciated.